# Magento 2.2. Get error with ''@param string[] $types' in REST API

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, json, parameter

Using magento 2.2. I create rest api for edit address which need pass param in 'array of string' but i get an error:

Doc: [Magento Configure services as web APIs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html)

Used array of string for pass param

> "street": ["new, wat phnom, phnom penh"]

Message

> "message": "Error occurred during \"street\" processing. Invalid type for value: \"array\". Expected Type: \"string\".",

My JSON

> {
>       "address":{
>           "addressId":85,
>           "street": ["new, wat phnom, phnom penh"],
>           "latitude":"11.33333664",
>           "longitude":"104.99778855"
>       }
>   }

Interface

```
<?php
namespace Iota\EShopping\Model\Address;

class Address
 {
private $addressId;
private $street;


/**
 * addressId
 * @return int
 */
public function getAddressId(){
    return $this->addressId;
}

/**
 * addressId
 * @param int $addressId
 * @return Address
 */
public function setAddressId($addressId){
    $this->addressId = $addressId;
    return $this;
}


/**
 * street
 * @return string
 */
public function getStreet(){
    return $this->street;
}

/**
 * street
 * @param string[] $street
 * @return Address
 */
public function setStreet($street){
    $this->street = $street;
    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: @return array|int|string|bool|float Scalar or array of scalars

Comment: Have you tried this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Valid scalar types** include: `mixed` (or anyType), `bool` (or boolean), `str` (or string), `integer` (or int), `float`, and `double`

Any parameters or return values of type array can be denoted by following any of the previous types by an empty set of square brackets []

```
@return array|int|string|bool|float Scalar or array of scalars
```

Comment: This returns: Class mixed does not exist. and with string[] returns: Class string[] does not exist. This is a magento issue?

Comment: No, please share your code.